# The http connection in Android emulator is unstable

Tags: android

I tried to make json requests, load images/videos from the local network with http ( not https), but it randomly fails. Sometimes the connection is closed before the data is received. The same error happens if I open Chrome, so it is not an error in my app.

How is it possible to debug an error like this?

Comment: 1. It's not android related if it happens in chrome too. 2. What error do you get? A javascript error? A HTTP 404/403/503? 3. If your app is built using webview, You can debug the error via Chrome's Dev Tools, the same way you would if it wasn't an app.

Comment: HTTP has errors, but HTTPS doesn't? That sounds like a server configuration problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem happens in Chrome, too, you can debug errors via `Remote Debugging`.

Instructions: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

In summary, you

1. Enable Developer Tools, and USB debugging on your phone.
2. Connect your phone to a computer via cable.
3. Turn Chrome on in both the phone and computer.
4. Use `Remote debugging` to use the computer's Chrome Dev Tools to inspect the Android tab.
5. Debug as normal, checking the console for network or javascript errors.